# Pandas Copy columns from one data frame to another with different name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have to copy columns from one DataFrame `A` to another DataFrame `B`.   The column names in `A` and `B` do not match.

What is the best way to do it? There are several columns like this. Do I need to write for each column like `B["SO"] = A["Sales Order"]` etc.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to ask understandable questions and receive understandable answers.

Answer (score 4):

i would use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

```
combined_df = pd.concat([df1, df2[['column_a', 'column_b']]], axis=1)
```

also gives you the power to concat different size dateframes , outer join etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
      'SO':list('abcdef'),
      'RI':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
      'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

})

print (df1)
  SO  RI  C
0  a   4  7
1  b   5  8
2  c   4  9
3  d   5  4
4  e   5  2
5  f   4  3

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

print (df2)
   D  E  F
0  1  5  a
1  3  3  a
2  5  6  a
3  7  9  b
4  1  2  b
5  0  4  b
```

Create dictionary for rename, select columns matched, rename by `dict` and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original - DataFrames matched by index values:

```
d =  {'SO':'Sales Order',
     'RI':'Retail Invoices'}


df11 = df1[d.keys()].rename(columns=d)
print (df11)
  Sales Order  Retail Invoices
0           a                4
1           b                5
2           c                4
3           d                5
4           e                5
5           f                4
```

---

```
df = df2.join(df11)
print (df)
   D  E  F Sales Order  Retail Invoices
0  1  5  a           a                4
1  3  3  a           b                5
2  5  6  a           c                4
3  7  9  b           d                5
4  1  2  b           e                5
5  0  4  b           f                4
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary of abbreviations. And try this code.

**Ex:**

```
full_form_dict =  {'SO':'Sales Order',
                   'RI':'Retail Invoices',}

A_col = list(A.columns)

B_col = [v for k,v in full_form_dict.items() if k in A_col]
# to loop over A_col
# B_col = [v for col in A_col for k,v in full_form_dict.items() if k == col]
```