# Want to copy selected column from old dataframe to a new dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe named new_df and would like to create a new data and copy column "Close" to new dataframe to column named "Col1". I would then open another dataframe named new_df and copy "Close" to Column named "Col2" of the new dataframe already created.

It is imporantant to note that when importing column that the data column may vary in lenghth, meaning first column import may have 30 records and second column import may have 32 records.

```
df = pd.read_csv('RIO.L.csv',parse_dates=True)                  

df['Date_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format= '%d/%m/%Y')   

df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date_1']).year                
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date_1']).month              
df['Day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date_1']).day                  

df.sort_values(by=['Month','Year','Day'], inplace=True)


m_Year_Select = 2019
m_Month_Select =  5


v_data_select = (df['Year'] <= m_Year_Select) & (df['Month'] == m_month_Select)
new_df = df.loc[v_data_select]

print(new_df)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Copy columns from one data frame to another with different name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303169/pandas-copy-columns-from-one-data-frame-to-another-with-different-name)

Answer (score 0):

I used the pd.concat()

result = pd.concat([result, df_2000['Close']], axis=1, sort=False, join='outer')

Problem solved